# How to build QM with projective spaces from the beginning?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, hilbert-space

In conventional treatment of QM, one assumes that (1) physical states are *normalized* vectors in (rigged) Hilbert spaces and (2) operators correspond to observables, with their eigenvectors denoting states where the observable is equal to the corresponding  eigenvalue.

From this, almost everything else follows, if we don't aspire to a von Neumann level of rigour. In particular, (1) is enough to derive that the evolution operator $U(t)$ is unitary and thus the infinitesimal evolution operator $-iH$ is anti-Hermitian, and (2) in conjunction with $\mathbf R$-valued observables in real life means that the observables are represented by Hermitian operators.

A better approach is to recognize that the normalization in (1) means we are now talking about *projective* Hilbert spaces. (2) then transforms into expressions like $\mathop{\mathrm {Tr}} \rho A$, $\rho = \psi\otimes\psi^\dagger$, etc. The general framework is clear to me. However, I’ve yet to see a text that tells this story systematically from the start, without references[1] to the conventional viewpoint, and in particular, points out the exact set of things we must take on faith to proceed in this manner, like my sketch above. Can anyone suggest such a text? A textbook would be perfect, but anything below the level of Deligne would do.

[1] What is called *normative* references in engineering standards, not comparisons, of course.

Comment: I do not know a source that starts from a $C^*$-algebraic point of view (that seems the suitable one for you). Anyways, in quantum mechanics it is essentially equivalent to deal with the usual Schrödinger representation or go with other more sophisticated approaches (because of the Stone-von Neumann theorem essentially), so people tend to prefer the one that has been historically developed first (I think). Things change when dealing with relativistic quantum mechanics, i.e. QFT, where there are infinitely many inequivalent representations, and a more general approach is desirable/necessary.

Comment: @yuggib I’m not sure it’s the $C^*$-algebraic approach I’m looking for: as far as I understand its point is to work with the observables without touching the (projective) Hilbert space of states for as long as possible. What I’m searching for is a description which would work with a space of states, but, for example, for a two-state system it would be the Bloch sphere and not the usual $\mathbb C^2$. Geometric quantum mechanics by Ashtekar and others may or may not be it, which is why I’m asking.

Comment: The space of states in the $C^*$-algebraic approach is not the whole dual of the algebra, but only the positive elements of norm one.